# How to Install Swagger to Laravel 8 API for documentation?

Tags: php, laravel-8

**Installing Swagger for the First Time in laravel 8**

```
composer require "darkaonline/l5-swagger"
composer require zircote/swagger-php
php artisan vendor:publish --provider "L5Swagger\L5SwaggerServiceProvider"
```

**Getting Error like:**

[image]

Comment: here is easiest way given  https://youtu.be/q1UttpUXB3s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the URL you're hitting might be incorrect. Change it to just `docs/api-docs` instead of `docs/api-docs.json`. In addition, if you haven't ran the generate command already, you would have to do so to make it work.

```
php artisan l5-swagger:generate
```